# How can I achieve my expected result?

Tags: mips

I want my program to do the following:

test $t0 and $t1. If they are equal print "Equal". If not, print "not Equal". Then test which one of them is Greater and which one of them is Lesser. Finally, print a message accordingly.

The problem with this code is, it doesn't strop after printing "Greater Than". It continues further to print "Lesser Than".

How can I achieve my expected result?

```
.data
    equals: .asciiz "\nEqual"
    notEquals: .asciiz "\nnot Equal"
    greaterThans: .asciiz "\nGreater Than"
    lessThans: .asciiz "\nLesser Than"
.text
    main:
        li $t0, 5
        li $t1, 125

        beq $t0, $t1, messageEqual
        bne $t0, $t1, messageNotEqual
        bgt $t0, $t1, messageGreaterThan
        blt $t0, $t1, messageLessThan   

        #Declare the end of the program
        li $v0, 10
        syscall

    messageEqual:
        la $a0, equals
        li $v0, 4
        syscall

    messageNotEqual:
        la $a0, notEquals
        li $v0, 4
        syscall 

    messageGreaterThan:
        la $a0, greaterThans
        li $v0, 4
        syscall 

    messageLessThan:
        la $a0, lessThans
        li $v0, 4
        syscall
```

Answer (score 0):

> it doesn't stop after printing "Greater Than". It continues further to print "Lesser Than".

Of course it does, since the code for printing "Lesser Than" directly follows the code for printing "Greater Than", and you haven't put any code in between to divert the flow of execution. A label isn't some kind of magic barrier, it's just a covenient name for a specific location in the program.

If you're running your program in SPIM/MARS and want to terminate it after printing a message you should use syscall 10 (`exit`). You've got one after all of your conditional jumps, but there's nothing in your code that will jump back to that location.

So instead you could do this:

```
messageGreaterThan:
    la $a0, greaterThans
    li $v0, 4
    syscall
    li $v0, 10
    syscall      # exit
```

You should do the same thing at all the other places where you're printing messages.
Slightly cleaner would be to do something like this:

```
# ...

messageNotEqual:
    # code for printing string omitted
    j exit

messageGreaterThan:
    # code for printing string omitted
    j exit

exit:
    li $v0, 10
    syscall      # exit
```

Comment: Neither of them are appropriate. What if I need to add some code just after the  `beq $t0, $t1, messageEqual  
        bne $t0, $t1, messageNotEqual  
        bgt $t0, $t1, messageGreaterThan  
        blt $t0, $t1, messageLessThan`   
, but, before
        `#Declare the end of the program 
        li $v0, 10 
        syscall`

Comment: Then place the `exit:` label right after the `blt`. Or convert your printing "subroutines" to proper functions that you call with `jal`, and which return with `jr $ra`.

Comment: A conditional `jal` can be achieved by combining it with a conditional branch (e.g. invert the condition on the conditional branch, so that you skip over the `jal` when the function shouldn't be called).